# Node JS on a Pi Zero multiple processes

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, pm2

I am using Node on a pi zero running raspbian stretch lite.

I basically want to have two processes running, one process is to keep a connection open to the server to push and receive messages like offline status and the other is to scan for iBeacons.

Would it be best practice to create one project and have two JSfiles and start them separately using something like PM2? Or would it be better to have two completely separate projects? The one process kind of relies on the other as I will be updating the beacons to scan for via the open connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running the applications as two separate processes, [PM2 allows you to control the startup of the two simultaneously through a JavaScript object, JSON, or YAML configuration file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/).

For instance, running both a `worker.js` and `api.js` script separately:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name        : "worker",
    script      : "./worker.js",
    watch       : true
  }, {
    name       : "api-app",
    script     : "./api.js",
    instances  : 4,
    exec_mode  : "cluster"
  }]
}
```

In that sense you can keep them as one single project, and then start them up together using a single configuration file with PM2.

If the complexity of your applications gets to the point where it might be better to split them up, you can do that as well later on.

Comment: Will give it a go. Thanks! Ideally I do want it in one project but was not sure if it's structurally correct or best practice to do that.

Comment: @SashaStojanovic Generally it's based on complexity, I'd probably keep it as a single project until it gets to the point where they can be decoupled enough to be 2.

Comment: I've edited my question just to add one more aspect in about DB usage with multiple process. Clarence, would you have further advise on that?

Comment: SQLite allows multiple processes to access a database at once, it’s just that changes (writes) to the data are controlled with locking, which can potentially be slower.  Are both processes writing to the database or is one only reading data?  I’d consider making this a separate question since it’s very different than the original ask.

Comment: Alright, I've asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171089/db-for-pi-zero-running-multiple-nodejs-processes

Comment: @SashaStojanovic Please accept this answer too if it helped answer your original question.

Answer (score 0):

As you likely get callbacks for detected beacons and the frequency will not be high, I would have implemented it as one process. The tricky thing with beacons is rather to handle entering/exiting regions that avoids "stuttering", so optimally there's one timer per detected timer that keeps tracks of entering/exiting far/near/immediate, if you now need such granularity.