# DB for Pi Zero running multiple NodeJs processes

Tags: node.js, database, raspberry-pi

I need a local DB on a pi zero, with multiple processes running that need to write and read data. That kind of rules SQLite out (I think). From my experience SQLite only allows one connection at a time and is tricky with multiple processes trying to do database work. All of my data transmission would be JSON driven so NOSQL makes sense but I need something light weight to store a few configs and to store data that will synced up to the server. But what NOSQL options would be best to run on a pi with great NODE support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is generally fine when using it with multiple concurrent processes.  From the SQLite FAQ:

> We are aware of no other embedded SQL database engine that supports as much concurrency as SQLite. SQLite allows multiple processes to have the database file open at once, and for multiple processes to read the database at once. When any process wants to write, it must lock the entire database file for the duration of its update. But that normally only takes a few milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer to finish then continue about their business. Other embedded SQL database engines typically only allow a single process to connect to the database at once.

For the majority of applications, that should be fine.  If only one of your processes is doing writes, and the other only reads, it should have no impact at all.

If you're looking for something that's NoSQL-specific, you can also consider [LevelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB), which is used in Google Chrome.  With Node, the best way to access it is through the [levelup](https://github.com/Level/levelup) library.

Comment: Thanks Clarence! Appreciate it, will reevaluate SQLite again.